# Observable error

Tags: java, swing, listener, observable

What does the error "The method setChanged() from type Observable is not visible" mean? I tried looking in the documentation and I didn't find anything for setting an observable object to visible. Here is my code:

```
       Observable observable = new Observable();
       //adding a listener to a button 
       @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            observable.setChanged();
            observable.notifyObservers(Main.this);

        }
    });
```

Comment: What does "protected" mean in this method signature: protected void setChanged()?

Comment: Oh does this mean it doesn't accept it because it's in a public method?

Comment: It means you cannot access it because it's not accessible as per its visibility modifier.

Comment: @nrubin29 But I can't reduce the visibility of a method inherited from the ActionListener class - is there a way around this?

Comment: @mttdbrd I know what they mean, I asked a direct question so if you don't want to answer it - just don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As defined [in the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#setChanged%28%29), the method `setChanged` is protected, and so available only to the class/subclasses:

```
protected void setChanged()
```

If you want to notify the observers about a change, call `notifyObservers`.

Comment: Thanks, I read somewhere that notifyObservers() will not do anything without using setChanged first? And obviously because I can't reduce the visibility of a method inherited from the ActionListener class there is not much I can do about that either.

Comment: @user3281466 Since it's `protected`, its not meant to be called outside of the rest of the Java API (within that package and subpackages I believe; not quite sure what protected denotes vs. default).

Comment: But there must me a way around this - there must be some other way of letting the observers know something has changed as soon as a button has been pressed?

Comment: @nrubin29 default is effectively the same as package. Observable is meant to be subclassed. From the docs: "This class represents an observable object, or "data" in the model-view paradigm. It can be subclassed to represent an object that the application wants to have observed.
An observable object can have one or more observers. An observer may be any object that implements interface Observer. After an observable instance changes, an application calling the Observable's notifyObservers method causes all of its observers to be notified of the change by a call to their update method."

Comment: and because it needs to be subclassed, it is difficult to use because there is no multiple inheritance in java. as a result, one sometimes/often has to delegate instead of subclass...